# Getting error on constructors using reactiveui

Tags: c#, .net, reactive, reactiveui

I have a view model that has two view models as properties:

```
    public class PokemonViewModel : ReactiveObject, IEnableLogger
    {
        private readonly IPokemonService PokemonService;

        [Reactive]
        public PokemonListViewModel PokemonListViewModel { get; set; }


        private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<PokemonDetailsViewModel> pokemonDetailsViewModel;
        public PokemonDetailsViewModel PokemonDetailsViewModel => pokemonDetailsViewModel.Value;

        public PokemonViewModel(IPokemonService pokemonService = null)
        {
            PokemonService = pokemonService ?? Locator.Current.GetService<IPokemonService>();

            PokemonListViewModel = new PokemonListViewModel();

            pokemonDetailsViewModel = this.WhenAnyValue(x => PokemonListViewModel.SelectedPokemon)
                .SelectMany(GetPokemonDetailsViewModelAsync)
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.PokemonDetailsViewModel);
        }

        //private methods...
    }
```

The `PokemonListViewModel` contains a `SelectedPokemon` property which is not initialized on constructor, so it's null at startup

Given this, when I run the application, I get the following error: `"Unsupported expression of type 'Constant'. Did you miss the member access prefix in the expression?"`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `x => x.PokemonListViewModel` in the WhenAnyValue call.